# How to resolve error "KeyError: 'Class' " in python code on google colab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, keyerror

I am trying to run my code for the decision tree and getting error
here is the traceback
I am facing this problem of key error frequently while implementation of the decision tree.

It is stated to have some key error but key name it is showing is 'class'. How is it possible?

This is code

It is the implementation of Decision tree with post pruning.

```py
  
import warnings
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import math
import random
import copy
import sys

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

print("Please wait to complete!")

def entropyCalculator(labels):
    total = labels.shape[0]
    ones = labels.sum().sum()
    zeros = total - ones
    if total == ones or total == zeros:
        return 0
    entropy = -(ones/total)*math.log(ones/total, 2) - (zeros/total)*math.log(zeros/total,2)
#     print ( "ones : " + str(ones) + "zeros : " + str(zeros) + "entropy : " + str(entropy))
    return entropy

# print(entropyCalculator(df[['Class']]))

def informationGain(featurelabels):
    total = featurelabels.shape[0]
    ones = featurelabels[featurelabels[featurelabels.columns[0]] == 1].shape[0]
    zeros = featurelabels[featurelabels[featurelabels.columns[0]] == 0].shape[0]
    parentEntropy = entropyCalculator(featurelabels[['Class']])
    entropyChildWithOne = entropyCalculator(featurelabels[featurelabels[featurelabels.columns[0]] == 1][['Class']])
    entropyChildWithZero = entropyCalculator(featurelabels[featurelabels[featurelabels.columns[0]] == 0][['Class']])
#     print ("left entropy : " + str(entropyChildWithZero))
#     print ("right entropy : " + str(entropyChildWithOne))
    infoGain = parentEntropy - (ones/total)*entropyChildWithOne - (zeros/total)*entropyChildWithZero
    return infoGain

# informationGain(df[['XB', 'Class']])

def findBestAttribute(data):
    maxInfoGain = -1.0
    for x in data.columns:
        if x == 'Class':
            continue
        currentInfoGain = informationGain(data[[x, 'Class']])
#         print(str(currentInfoGain) + " " + x)
        if maxInfoGain < currentInfoGain:
            maxInfoGain = currentInfoGain
            bestAttribute = x
    return bestAttribute
# findBestAttribute(df)

class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.attribute = None
        self.nodeType = None # L/R/I leaf/Root/Intermidiate 
        self.value = None # attributes split's value 0 or 1
        self.positiveCount = None
        self.negativeCount = None
        self.label = None
        self.nodeId = None
    
    def setNodeValue(self, attribute, nodeType, value = None, positiveCount = None, negativeCount = None):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.nodeType = nodeType
        self.value = value
        self.positiveCount = positiveCount
        self.negativeCount = negativeCount

class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()
        self.root.setNodeValue('$@$', 'R')
        
    def createDecisionTree(self, data, tree):
        global nodeCount
        total = data.shape[0]
        ones = data['Class'].sum()
        zeros = total - ones        
        if data.shape[1] == 1 or total == ones or total == zeros:
            tree.nodeType = 'L'
            if zeros >= ones:
                tree.label = 0
            else:
                tree.label = 1
            return        
        else:        
            bestAttribute = findBestAttribute(data)
            tree.left = Node()
            tree.right = Node()
            
            tree.left.nodeId = nodeCount
            nodeCount=nodeCount+1
            tree.right.nodeId = nodeCount
            nodeCount=nodeCount+1
            
            tree.left.setNodeValue(bestAttribute, 'I', 0, data[(data[bestAttribute]==0) & (df['Class']==1) ].shape[0], data[(data[bestAttribute]==0) & (df['Class']==0) ].shape[0])
            tree.right.setNodeValue(bestAttribute, 'I', 1, data[(data[bestAttribute]==1) & (df['Class']==1) ].shape[0], data[(data[bestAttribute]==1) & (df['Class']==0) ].shape[0])
            self.createDecisionTree( data[data[bestAttribute]==0].drop([bestAttribute], axis=1), tree.left)
            self.createDecisionTree( data[data[bestAttribute]==1].drop([bestAttribute], axis=1), tree.right)
            
    def printTreeLevels(self, node,level):
        if(node.left is None and node.right is not None):
            for i in range(0,level):    
                print("| ",end="")
            level = level + 1
            print("{} = {} (ID:{}) : {}".format(node.attribute, node.value,(node.nodeId if node.nodeId is not None else ""),(node.label if node.label is not None else "")))
            self.printTreeLevels(node.right,level)
        elif(node.right is None and node.left is not None):
            for i in range(0,level):    
                print("| ",end="")
            level = level + 1
#            print("{} = {} : {}".format(node.attribute, node.value,(node.label if node.label is not None else "")))
            print("{} = {} (ID:{}) : {}".format(node.attribute, node.value,(node.nodeId if node.nodeId is not None else ""),(node.label if node.label is not None else "")))
            self.printTreeLevels(node.left,level)
        elif(node.right is None and node.left is None):
            for i in range(0,level):    
                print("| ",end="")
            level = level + 1
            print("{} = {} (ID:{}) : {}".format(node.attribute, node.value,(node.nodeId if node.nodeId is not None else ""),(node.label if node.label is not None else "")))
        else:
            for i in range(0,level):    
                print("| ",end="")
            level = level + 1
            print("{} = {} (ID:{}) : {}".format(node.attribute, node.value,(node.nodeId if node.nodeId is not None else ""),(node.label if node.label is not None else "")))
            self.printTreeLevels(node.left,level)
            self.printTreeLevels(node.right,level)
    
    def printTree(self, node):
        self.printTreeLevels(node.left,0)
        self.printTreeLevels(node.right,0)
    
    def predictLabel(self, data, root):
        if root.label is not None:
            return root.label
        elif data[root.left.attribute][data.index.tolist()[0]] == 1:
            return self.predictLabel(data, root.right)
        else:
            return self.predictLabel(data, root.left)

    def countNodes(self,node):
        if(node.left is not None and node.right is not None):
            return 2 + self.countNodes(node.left) + self.countNodes(node.right)
        return 0

    
    def countLeaf(self,node):
        if(node.left is None and node.right is None):
            return 1
        return self.countLeaf(node.left) + self.countLeaf(node.right)

def searchNode(tree, x):
    tmp = None
    res = None
    if(tree.nodeType != "L"):
        if(tree.nodeId == x):
            return tree
        else:
            res = searchNode(tree.left,x)
            if (res is None):
                res = searchNode(tree.right,x)
            return res
    else:
        return tmp

def postPruning(pNum,newTree):
    
    for i in range(pNum):
        x = random.randint(2,pruneTree.countNodes(pruneTree.root)-1)
        tempNode = Node()
        tempNode = searchNode(newTree,x)

        if(tempNode is not None):
            tempNode.left = None
            tempNode.right = None
            tempNode.nodeType = "L"
            if(tempNode.negativeCount >= tempNode.positiveCount):
                tempNode.label = 0
            else:
                tempNode.label = 1

def calculateAccuracy(data, tree):
    correctCount = 0
    for i in data.index:
        val = tree.predictLabel(data.iloc[i:i+1, :].drop(['Class'], axis=1),tree.root)
        if val == data['Class'][i]:
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
    return correctCount/data.shape[0]*100



pruneFactor = 0.05

df = df_train
dtest = df_test
dvalidation = df_val

# remove empty rows
df = df.dropna()
dtest = dtest.dropna()
dvalidation = dvalidation.dropna()

nodeCount = 0 # for node id



dtree = Tree()
dtree.createDecisionTree(df, dtree.root)

maxAccuracy = calculateAccuracy(dvalidation, dtree)
bestTree = copy.deepcopy(dtree)
countOfNodes = bestTree.countNodes(bestTree.root)
c = 0

while c < 10:    
    c += 1
    pruneNum = round(countOfNodes*pruneFactor)
#     print(pruneNum)
    pruneTree = Tree()
    pruneTree = copy.deepcopy(bestTree)
    postPruning(pruneNum,pruneTree.root)
    temp = calculateAccuracy(dvalidation, pruneTree)
    if temp > maxAccuracy:
#         print("Accuracy Improved")
        maxAccuracy = temp
        bestTree = copy.deepcopy(pruneTree)
        countOfNodes = bestTree.countNodes(bestTree.root)
        


print("-------------------------------------")
print("Pre-Pruned Tree")
print("-------------------------------------")
dtree.printTree(dtree.root)

print("")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("Pre-Pruned Accuracy")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("Number of training instances = " +str(df.shape[0]))
print("Number of training attributes = " +str(df.shape[1] -1))
print("Total number of nodes in the tree = "+ str(dtree.countNodes(dtree.root)))
print("Number of leaf nodes in the tree = " +str(dtree.countLeaf(dtree.root)))
print("Accuracy of the model on the training dataset = " + str(calculateAccuracy(df,dtree))+"%")
print("")
print("Number of validation instances = " +str(dvalidation.shape[0]))
print("Number of validation attributes = " +str(dvalidation.shape[1]-1))
print("Accuracy of the model on the validation dataset before pruning = "+ str(calculateAccuracy(dvalidation,dtree))+"%")
print("")
print("Number of testing instances = "+str(dtest.shape[0]))
print("Number of testing attributes = "+str(dtest.shape[1]-1))
print("Accuracy of the model on the testing dataset = "+ str(calculateAccuracy(dtest,dtree))+"%")

print("")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("Post-Pruned Tree")
print("-------------------------------------")
bestTree.printTree(bestTree.root)

print("")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("Post-Pruned Accuracy")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("Number of training instances = " + str(df.shape[0]))
print("Number of training attributes = " + str(df.shape[1] - 1))
print("Total number of nodes in the tree = " + str(bestTree.countNodes(bestTree.root)))
print("Number of leaf nodes in the tree = " + str(bestTree.countLeaf(bestTree.root)))
print("Accuracy of the model on the training dataset = " + str(calculateAccuracy(df, bestTree)) + "%")
print("")
print("Number of validation instances = " + str(dvalidation.shape[0]))
print("Number of validation attributes = " + str(dvalidation.shape[1] - 1))
print("Accuracy of the model on the validation dataset after pruning = " + str(calculateAccuracy(dvalidation, bestTree)) + "%")
print("")
print("Number of testing instances = " + str(dtest.shape[0]))
print("Number of testing attributes = " + str(dtest.shape[1] - 1))
print("Accuracy of the model on the testing dataset = " + str(calculateAccuracy(dtest, bestTree)) + "%")
print("")
if(maxAccuracy > calculateAccuracy(dvalidation, dtree)):
    print("Successfully Pruned with improvement in Accuracy on validation data set.")
else:
    print("Pruned but Accuracy didn't improved after 10 attempts so returning same tree.")
```

Here is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Class'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
<ipython-input-15-babebb234de5> in <module>()
      1 dtree = Tree()
----> 2 dtree.createDecisionTree(df, dtree.root)
      3 
      4 maxAccuracy = calculateAccuracy(dvalidation, dtree)
      5 bestTree = copy.deepcopy(dtree)

<ipython-input-13-188b2bef3d66> in createDecisionTree(self, data, tree)
     78       global nodeCount
     79       total = data.shape[0]
---> 80       ones = data['Class'].sum()
     81       zeros = total - ones
     82       if data.shape[1] == 1 or total == ones or total == zeros:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2904             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2905                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2906             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2907             if is_integer(indexer):
   2908                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Class'
```

Comment: can you also add your code

Comment: Yes Sure @UtpalDutt